# installing CakePhp: "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages" error

Tags: php, curl, cakephp, composer-php, phpcodesniffer

I'm trying to install cakephp using composer with this [tutorial](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html) but after I run the command:

```
sudo composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app my_app_name
```

I get the error:

> Problem 1
>       - cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer 3.0.0 requires squizlabs/php_codesniffer ^3.0.0 -> satisfiable by squizlabs/php_codesniffer[3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.1.0, 3.1.1].
>       - cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer 3.0.1 requires squizlabs/php_codesniffer ^3.0.0 -> satisfiable by squizlabs/php_codesniffer[3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.1.0, 3.1.1].
>       - squizlabs/php_codesniffer 3.1.1 requires ext-simplexml * -> the requested PHP extension simplexml is missing from your system.
>       - squizlabs/php_codesniffer 3.1.0 requires ext-simplexml * -> the requested PHP extension simplexml is missing from your system.
>       - squizlabs/php_codesniffer 3.0.2 requires ext-simplexml * -> the requested PHP extension simplexml is missing from your system.
>       - squizlabs/php_codesniffer 3.0.1 requires ext-simplexml * -> the requested PHP extension simplexml is missing from your system.
>       - squizlabs/php_codesniffer 3.0.0 requires ext-simplexml * -> the requested PHP extension simplexml is missing from your system.
>       - Installation request for cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer ^3.0 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer[3.0.0, 3.0.1].
>
> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini
>   files:
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini   You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

I installed [codeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) using both curl and composer. still I can't get rid of the error. any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you don't have one of those extension installed on your web server

Comment: @madalinivascu but I followed the tutorial steps.So shouldn't they be installed? and how can I tell which one?

Comment: Read the error message closely, it tells you wich extensions are missing: "_squizlabs/php_codesniffer 3.1.1 requires **ext-simplexml** * -> the requested PHP extension **simplexml** is missing from your system_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like codeSniffer requires squizlabs ^3.0.0. 
And it also looks like you need to enable extensions in your .ini files.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar error at one point. It was fixed by installing php-xml. Make sure you install what waris said also.

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error at one point. It was fixed by installing php-xml. Make sure you install what waris said also.
first php version

```
php -v
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install <your php version>-xml
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install some extension i-e:

```
sudo pear install PHP_CodeSniffer
```

And also  enable the php extensions for composer i-e curl,intl

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install curl php-cli php-mbstring git unzip
```

**extra options:**

to install composer globally :

```
sudo php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Comment: if still exist any extension to enable mention here i help you

Comment: PEAR is dead, and installing PHPCS that way instead of via composer won't fix the underlying problem, which, as the error message suggests, is that the the SimpleXML extension is missing.

Comment: try this for xml  `sudo apt-get install php-xml`